# Should I close store while using "runAsync" method of Flutter Objectbox (Objectbox version 1.5.0)

Tags: flutter, dart, objectbox

Should close the store when interacting whith objectbox store in other thread with its method. (Flutter version 3.0.0, Objectbox version 1.5.0)

```
String? readNameAndRemove(Store store, int objectId){
    var box = store.box<User>();
    final nameOrNull = box.get(objectId)?.name;
    box.remove(objectId);
    return nameOrNull;
}
await store.runAsync(readNameAndRemove, objectId);
```

Comment: I guess it shouldn't hurt to close it explicitly? It's "nice" to do so to ensure resources are freed early, but I believe it's already done internally. Any specific trigger for this question?

Comment: No need to, [the store used by the worker isolate is closed](https://github.com/objectbox/objectbox-dart/blob/v1.5.0/objectbox/lib/src/native/store.dart#L508) in any case, even if the callback throws. Any reason why you would think you have to do this? E.g. some docs we maybe should update?

Comment: Thank you Markus Junginger and Uwe - Objectbox for answer. Before v1.4.0, I used to close the store which shared from Store.fromReference. So I thought that again I have to do it. But thank you for url link, and I made sure.